# Prove wether or not the following series diverges or converges: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^nn\over n+1}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Prove wether or not the following series diverges or converges:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^nn\over n+1}$

I am just not sure, I know if I use the absolute value test for convergence and root test it is inconclusive.

I was then thinking of using nth term test however I have the $(-1)^n$, can I just ignore that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What can you say about
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^nn}{n+1}?$$

Look at
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n+1}$$
first.

Comment: ye I know that limit goes to one meaning the sum of the absolute series diverges, however that doesnt help since that doesn't prove that the alternating series converges or diverges, right?

Comment: Well, since $\lim n/(n+1)=1$, $\lim (-1)^nn/(n+1)$ does not exist.

Comment: the limit of any alternating series does not exist right, and if it doesn't exist does that mean it 'always' diverges?

Comment: $\lim (-1)^n/n=0$.

Comment: oh ok thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

As ${(-1)^nn\over n+1}\not\to 0$ the series does not converge.

Comment: Oh so I can apply the nth term test to a series by just ignoring the $(-1)^n$ ?

Comment: Because if so then I understand why it diverges

Comment: @user2250537, the *necessary* condition is $\lim a_n = 0$. If this is false, maybe $\exists\lim a_n = l\ne 0$, maybe  $\not\exists\lim a_n$,

Answer (score 1):

**Fact.** Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence. Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$
if and only if
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert a_n\right\rvert=0$

Now, we wish to investigate the convergence of $\sum a_n$ where $\displaystyle a_n=(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+1}$.

To do so, let's apply the [Divergence Test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Divergence_Test).

Note that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert a_n\right\rvert
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert (-1)^n\frac{n}{n+1}\right\rvert
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}
= 1
$$
It follows that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq0$. Hence $\sum a_n$ diverges.

Comment: What I have just done is, see we can separate the given series in even and odd so $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n n}{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{2n}{2n+1} - \frac{2n-1}{2n} \right) $$ Now $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n n}{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{n^2 + n/2} $$  And this converges... Can't we do such rearrangement?